# How can I build a fat jar to build my Chisel code with sbt-assembly?

Tags: sbt, chisel, sbt-assembly

I would like to build a fat JAR that can build my Chisel code.  I have built these previously using Maven assembly:
https://github.com/hutch31/ChiselCodeGenerator

But I would like to get this working with chisel 3.5 and sbt-assembly, which I have done this branch:
https://github.com/hutch31/ChiselCodeGenerator/tree/chisel3.5

Per the docs I simply add the dependency and go, but it's unable to resolve the dependency when I do so:

```
not found: /home/guy/.ivy2/localcom.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.13/sbt_1.0/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.13_1.0/1.2.0/sbt-assembly-1.2.0.pom
(ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.13:1.2.0
```